# Method Syntax with restrictions not running

Tags: ruby, methods, syntax-error

I am learning Ruby using codecademy and the current exercise tells the user to :

Define two methods in the editor:

A `greeter` method that takes a single string parameter, name, and returns a string greeting that person. (Make sure to use return and don't use print or puts.)

A `by_three?` method that takes a single integer parameter, number, and returns true if that number is evenly divisible by three and false if not. Remember, it's a Ruby best practice to end method names that produce boolean values with a question mark.

Based on that I came up with some code but it doesn't work and I do not know how to fix it or what I am missing. Any push in the right direction is greatly appreciated! Here is my code :

```
def greeter (name)

name = gets.chomp
return "Hi there #{name} sucka!"
end

def by_three(number)

number = gets.chomp
if number % 3 == 0
return true
else return false
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider something like this:

```
def greeter(name)
  "Hi there #{name}!"
end

def by_three?(number)
  number % 3 == 0
end
```

You can check these in `irb`:

```
1.9.3p327 :010 >   greeter 'joe'
 => "Hi there joe!" 
1.9.3p327 :011 > by_three? 9
 => true 
1.9.3p327 :012 > by_three? 10
 => false
```

**Notes:**

In `ruby`, it's common practice to not use `return` unless it's absolutely necessary, since the result of the last expression executed in the method is automatically returned as the value of the method.

Also, my interpretation of the question you're working on looks like it wants your methods to take parameters, so I've removed the `gets` calls to read from standard input, and instead expect the methods to operate on the parameter passed to it.  (Though I could certainly be wrong in my reading of the codeacademy question.)

Comment: Thank you! That was spot on helpful! It looks like I just over complicated it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
def by_three(number)
   number = gets.chomp
   if number.to_i % 3 == 0
      return true
   else return false
end
```

you forgot to  convert the number into integer, thats why the code is not working.

Comment: Good point. Not he point of the exercise but I will keep that in mind for later! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def by_three?(number)
    if !number
        number = gets.chomp
    end

    if ("" << number.to_s) =~ /^(\d)+$/
        number.to_i % 3 == 0
    else
        false
    end 
end
```

I think this is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def greeter(name)
  return ("greeting " + name)
end 

greeter("rahul")

def by_three?(number, i)

    if number % 3 == i
        i % 2 == 0 
        return "true"
    else 
        return "false"
    end

    end 
    by_three?(12,1)
```

This might help